# Trying to find the rarest properties in percentage of a character from dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

so i have a dataset like below in pandas:

```
       outfit    face          hat     skin    background   weapon
0.   cyberpunk.  angry.       none.   purple.  black.      sword
1.   formal.     smile   cowboy hat.  normal.  pink.       pistol
2    police.     smile.       cop.    dark.    white.      pepper spray
```

the above is just an example i have more then 1000 data like above every character have different traits.
what i really want is to get the rariest character from the rows with percentange in new column.

like example first the data is calculated by every column what is the least occcured item and when averaging it by row find the rariest row.

example if row 2 has the rariest trait like only 22 have smile face, 34 have cop hat, 8 have dark skin, 50 have background whit and 5 have pepper spray as weapon out of 1ooo data it should will be the rariest character and a new column will show data average % of rarity.

I know its long but i don't know how to get this out put so any expert guidance will be appreciated.

Thank you in adavnce

Comment: One way is to use `pd.value_count()` to find the frequency of each entry in every column. Then take an average of these frequencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elaborating on my comment,

one way to solve the problem is to calculate the normalized frequency of each cell with respect to that column and store it.

Finally, calculate the mean across each row and append it back into the original dataframe.

```py
import pandas as pd
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
for column in df:
    new_df[column] = df[column].value_counts(normalize=True) * 100
df['avg'] = new_df.mean(axis=1)
```

**Note**: I haven't tested the code yet and it's based on what I remember, I will try to run it on sample data tomorrow morning, let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: the "avg" column has NaN in all

Comment: @Zac Can you share more entries from the dataset?

Comment: can you tell me how can i find words occurance in a column like above df in column face, angry,smile,sad,happy comes how do i get how many time each words comesin column face?